regex to match starting numbering or alphabet bullets like (a)
I am trying to find whether string(sentence) starts with numbering or alphabet bullets followed by dot(.) or space. I have regex like:
r'^(\(\d|\[a-z]\))\s +'

and
r"^(?:\(\d+\)|\\[a-z]\.)\s*"

I tried it on example strings:
(a). this is bullet 
Not a bullet,
(b) its bullet again
I am so relaxed that its not bullet.
(1) Bullet again.

But when I try
matches = re.findall(pattern, text, re.M)

I get an empty list. How can I fix it?

You seem to be guessing with where and how many backslashes to insert. You can use a site like https://regex101.com/ to check what a regex means and whether it makes sense for your case.

@mkrieger1 good point, edited the regex for alphabets as well.  Trying the platform provided by you now. Thanks

Got it. Correct regex: pattern = r"^(?:(\w+)|\[0-9].)\s*". Thanks

\w already matches all alpha-numeric characters and underscore. You don't need to explicitly include the number range. Also \[ is wrong. The only reason it's working is because \w is already doing all the work.

If you are trying to capture the entire bullet, this is the proper regex r'\(\w+\)[. ]'

I have never seen the format with both parentheses and a dot. Another common variant is with just the closing paren, like a) one, b) two

Executable code in Python
Solution
import re
content = """
(a). this is bullet 
Not a bullet,
(b) its bullet again
I am so relaxed that its not bullet.
(1) Bullet again.
"""

patter_str = r'\((?:\w+)\)\.?\s.*'
pattern = re.compile(patter_str)
matches = pattern.findall(content)
for item in matches:
    print(item)

Output
(a). this is bullet 
(b) its bullet again
(1) Bullet again.

EDIT
If you want to rescue the text after the bullet you can use this pattern:
patter_str = r'\((?:\w+)\)\.?\s(.*)'


You don't need \d. \w matches all alpha-numeric characters and underscore.

Thanks for the help, the change was added to the new EDIT

FYI, (?:\w+) = \w+.

About the patterns that you tried:

In your first pattern ^(\(\d|\[a-z]\))\s + the parenthesis are not correct as they are inside of the grouping, and at the end of the pattern it matches a whitespace char and 1 or more spaces (so at least 2 "spaces")

The second pattern ^(?:\(\d+\)|\\[a-z]\.)\s* has a match for (1)  because the parenthesis are only around the digits. Also there is an escaping issue for \\[a-z] and the dot is mandatory.


I think it is easier to spot when you break it down into separate parts, for example the first pattern:

^ Start of string
( Start capture group 1

\(\d Match ( and a digit
| Or
\[a-z]\) Match [a-z]) literally because you escaped the \[


) Close group 1
\s + Match a whitespace char and 1+ spaces


You could update the pattern as:
^\((?:\d|[a-z])\)[ .]

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
\( Match (

(?: Non capture group (you don't need a capture group for matching only)

\d Match a single digit (use \d+ to repeat 1 or more times)
| Or
[a-z] Match a single char a-z (use [a-z]+ to repeat 1 or more times)


) Close the non capture group


\) Match )
[ .] Match a space or a dot (or \s to match a whitespace character)

See a regex demo and a Python demo
Example (note to add .* to the end of the pattern to match the whole line)
import re

s = """(a). this is bullet 
Not a bullet,
(b) its bullet again
I am so relaxed that its not bullet.
(1) Bullet again."""

pattern = r'^\((?:\d|[a-z])\)[ .].*'
print(re.findall(pattern, s, re.M))

Output
[
  '(a). this is bullet ',
  '(b) its bullet again',
  '(1) Bullet again.'
]

